# How to create Android splash screen with gif image and progress bar?

Tags: android, android-intent, splash-screen

I'm an Android beginner. I am going to use Splash Screen to make a load screen now. 
What I want is that gif Image and progress bar will work until all the data is loaded on the Splash Screen.

Below is the code I referred to. I want to move on when all the data, not the time specified here, is uploaded.

I want you to help me.

```
public class LoadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  
@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){  
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
setContentView(R.layout.activity\_loading);

    ImageView splashGif = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.splash_gif_view);
    GlideDrawableImageViewTarget gifImage = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(splashGif);
    Glide.with(this).load(R.raw.splash).into(splashGif);

    startLoading();
}

private void startLoading() {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 5000);
}
}
```

Comment: How are you loading the data?  You need to add that part as well.

Answer (score -1):

So try making your splash screen as a fragment rather than an activity. 
This makes it possible to overlay your splash screen over the Main Activity and set visibility of  Splashscreen **View.GONE**  once your data is loaded. 
You can even pop of the fragment by `getFragmentManager().popBackStack();`

There is even a better way to handle this and the preferred way by professionals :

The use of Async Load : Refer 
[Async Load](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader)

CHOICE IS YOURS .